# Андроид отправка SMS сообщении

Tags: java, android

Есть база номеров моих постоянных клиентов. Я хотел написать приложение, которое может отправлять им SMS сообщения с моего номера. Как реализуется отправка сообщении в Андроид?

Comment: @yoralbayev Все, как всегда банально. Если ты решил, что-либо запилить, значит кто-то это уже сделал, ну по крайней мере попытался или делает до сих пор. Необходимо просто найти его, этого некто. Вот [например](https://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/) хороший пример.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отправить текстовое сообщение из приложения, в файл манифеста нужно добавить разрешение `android.permission.SEND_SMS` и затем воспользоваться классом
`android.telephony.SmsManager`.

Пример:

```
private void sendSmsMessage(String address, String message) throws Exception
{
    SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsMgr.sendTextMessage(address, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Параметры метода означают следующее: 
`address` - адрес получателя SMS-сообщения (его телефонный номер), 
`message` - текст смс-сообщения.

Comment: Примечание: для API >= 23 требуется получить ещё и динамическое разрешение (Dangerous Permission)